# How can I check if entity many-to-many relation was changed?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a user and user has roles.

I retrieved the user from repo and he has 3 roles.
I add one more role to user and at some point I call `UnitOfWork` to find out if user has got new roles?

But `getOriginalEntityData(user)` does not return this. I see I can use getScheduledCollectionUpdates but I am not sure how to deal with it.

Comment: Hello, I don't know why you had created a table for that, the basic behavior in this case is to use FOS/UserBundle, that manage roles in on column from an enum. You can check if an user is logged in with the framework security or more specifics rights with voters. Can you please try to explain what you want to do, and some source code ?

Comment: This is not Symfony Security roles, this is just an example, imagine entity Apartment instead =)

Comment: Can you describe a little more what you want to complete, please ? Or a little bit more of source code ?